# Getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Exception when trying to Create / Update / Delete / Query Rally through Rally API in java

Tags: java, api, rally, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

Getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Exception when trying to Create / Update / Delete / Query Rally through Rally API in java

```
// Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
    RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"sphoortix.patil@foo.com", "Foo@123");
    restApi.setWsapiVersion("v2.0");
    restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");


    //Query User
    QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
    String workSpace = userRequest.getWorkspace();
    userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
    userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "sphoortix.patil@foo.com"));
    QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
    JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
    JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
    JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
    String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

    // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
    QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
    testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
    testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC1147"));
    QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
    JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
```

I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

exception at every `restap.get` ; `restapi.create` and `restapi.query`

I don't what might be the problem, i assume it must due to SSO issue and also found source saying that Rally APIS require a Security Token when you are trying to do operation trough Rally APIs. Refer to [Rally Web Services API Documentation v2.0/Autorization](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/authentication.jsp)

Please guide / help.

Answer (score 1):

Rally's SDK Toolkits don't support SSO yet. If your organization uses SSO, you'll need to have your Rally admin add your UserID to a whitelist so that you can use either/or SSO/Rally credentials.

Note that the Java REST toolkit will handle all of the auth token management for you, so you don't need to worry about getting or maintaining an API auth key. The java toolkit does that for you.

The last possibility might be that you have a proxy server between you and Rally. If this is the case, you can configure your proxy via:

`restApi.setProxy(new URI(proxyserver));`